# Django sentry - request.sentry object

Tags: python, django, django-templates, sentry, raven

I'm trying to enable the user-feedback functionality on my project. I tried several things with no success so far. I'm using `django 1.11` and `raven 6.8.0`

I followed this solution too - [[DOCS] Django Integration for User Feedback](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/945)

Debugging a little bit around the js snippet:

```
{% if request.sentry.id %}
    <script>
        Raven.showReportDialog({
            // grab the eventId generated by the Sentry SDK
            eventId: '{{ request.sentry.id }}',

            // use the public DSN (dont include your secret!)
            dsn: 'dsn'
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

I noticed that there's no `sentry` object inside `request` but the `request` object is present in the `500.html` template

Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to improve the docs here, but see this example for how to get the request object into the 500 template:

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/#message-references

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. My problem is this: By default, Sentry will attach request.sentry when it catches a Django exception. This is not happening. In my local I see, object has no attribute 'sentry'

Comment: my bad, I had a configuration to avoid sending alerts on my dev environment, so that's why it was never attached. thanks